# How to calculate days worked together with different starting and ending dates for matched employees

Tags: javascript, dayjs

How to calculate days worked together with different starting and ending dates?

I receive an array with worker info [employeeID, projectID, startingDate, endDate]. I have already matched the employees who have worked on the same project. However, I am struggling to figure out how to calculate for how long they've worked together since both their starting and end dates are different.

Example:

```
[218, 10, 2012-05-16, 2013-05-16]
[132, 10, 2009-01-01, 2012-06-27]
```

I looked into dayJS and it will help calculating the final stretch. The issue is getting there.

This is my code:

```
export default function Dropzone() {

    const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState<Array<string[]> | null>(null)

    const [parsedCsvData, setParsedCsvData] = useState([])

    const parseFile = file => {
        Papa.parse(file, {
            complete: results => {
                const resData = results.data as unknown as Array<string[]>
                setCsvData(resData)
            }
        })
    }

    const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
        if (acceptedFiles.length) {
            parseFile(acceptedFiles[0])
        }
    }, [])

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({ onDrop });


    const projectData = new Map()

    if (csvData != null) {

        csvData.map((el: Array<string>) => {
            const projectIdKey = el[1]
            const employeeIdValue = el[0]

            if (projectData.has(projectIdKey)) {
                projectData.set(projectIdKey, [...projectData.get(projectIdKey), employeeIdValue])
            } else {
                projectData.set(el[1], [el[0]])
            }
        })
    }

    projectData.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (value.length == 2 && csvData != null) {
            const [employee1, employee2] = [...value]
            const dates = []
            csvData.map((el) => {
                if (el.includes(employee1) || el.includes(employee2)) {
                    dates.push(el[2], el[3])
                }

            })
            const date1 = dayjs(dates[0])
            const date3 = dayjs(dates[3])
            console.log(date3.diff(date1, 'day'))
        }
    })

    return (
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
            <input {...getInputProps()} type="file" accept=".csv" />
            <p>Click here to upload CSV files...</p>
            <ResultsTable csvData={csvData} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are currently using

Comment: To calculate how long two people have worked together, calculate the difference between: 1) the later of the 2 start dates and 2) the earlier of the 2 end dates. So long as the two people's work overlapped, that should give you the time they spent working together.

Comment: Please share a runnable example of your code, and reduce it to the parts that are crucial

Comment: I apologize for my poor formatting. @RockySims's suggestion was brilliant and it is now working!